# Accessing topicality of label - missing field in response

Tags: google-cloud-vision

As per [this](https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#EntityAnnotation) piece of documentation, there is the ability to access  topicality, something I really require when analyzing the response.

However, in all of the other examples, there is no presence of this field. In my own playing around, I also have not seen this field present.

What am I misunderstanding here?